# How to submit a external signal to my computer in a simple way?

Tags: linux, windows, signal

I have an electrical wire that have two states: 1/0. `1' means there is current while `0' means there is no current. How can I put these two states into a file of my computer in a simple way?

I know that I can use an advanced ammeter/voltmeter and use GPIB lines to realize this. But is there a really simple way to satisfy this really simple need? Besides, I use Linux/Windows. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What does the electrical wire use to interface with the computer? RS232? paralelle? USB? What are we talking about here?

Comment: GPIB is the simple way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest I can think of would be the audio port, because it's sitting there unused on most systems waiting for you to connect some leads to it.

Not sure how to connect your line voltage to that port?  Build the circuit described at the bottom of the page here: 
xoscope.sourceforge.net

testing this circuit should involve the application there 'xoscope' (i.e. hook up your new circuit to a source and watch the line dance as you change voltage)

Another idea might be to hook up an arduino (or some other 8bit dev board) and use one of the example sketches that deal with digital IO?

Answer (score 0):

Arduino or its .NET counterpart, NetDuino, is a hardware platform that will let you do this inexpensively.

http://arduino.cc/